# When the button is hovered the background-color of a class is forcibly changed to a different color

Tags: html, css

The pseudo element `::after` is used to create new content behind the button with the class name `.btn`.

For some reason the color `red` appears on the whole button when the `.btn--white` should stay `white` while it is hovered. The `z-index` of `.btn::after` is set to `-1` and it does a good job of hiding the color until the button is hovered.

The `background-color` that should be in `.btn--white::after` should be `white` and it does work as intended if the color `white` is chosen. The problem starts when it is chosen to be a different `background-color`, for example `red`.

Can this be fixed with just CSS?

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

.button-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.btn,
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
  /* opacity: 0; */
}

.btn:active {
  outline: none;
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn--white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

.btn--white::after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-box">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn--white">The Crazy Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your question exactly what effect you're trying to achieve. I'm guessing however that you'd like the button to remain `white` on hover, and for the `red` to show behind the button. See my example below.

The reason your button was changing colour to `red` is because the `::after` element is technically a child of the button, and was therefore appearing above the button on the Z axis.

To achieve your desired result, I created a `::before` element which inherits the button background colour, and positioned that above the `::after` element.

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

.button-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.btn,
.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.btn::before {
  background-color: inherit;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
  /* opacity: 0; */
}

.btn:active {
  outline: none;
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn--white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

.btn--white::after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-box">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn--white">The Crazy Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am glad that it solves the problem. I am still confused about why the inherited background-color was the red instead of white. I must be missing some inheritance concept or something.

Comment: Alright, so after some thinking I finally understood why it works. The size of .btn::before is the same as .btn, it covers the portion of background that would be red, so it ends up looking the way it should. Somehow I thought that ::before inherited the background-color of ::aftrer and somehow pushed the element behind the parent, I know i doesn't even make sense. The color of .btn::before truly is white :))

Comment: Exactly. And both the `::before` and `::after` elements are on top of the `.btn` element. So the `::before` element is simply masking part of the `::after` element.